# How to change the text of the "checkout" button in Drupal commerce cart?

Tags: commerce

How can I change the text of the "checkout" button in Drupal commerce cart?

I need it to be "continue" instead.

thanks

[image]

```
   function rooms_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {  
      dsm($form_id);  // print form ID to messages
      switch ($form_id){
            case 'views_form_commerce_cart_form_default':
                $action['#value'] = 'continue';
            break;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the string overrides module - http://drupal.org/project/stringoverrides

If you can get it to work, it is a great maintainable way to change text generated by modules

Comment: I will definitely try it. Looks good.

Answer (score 3):

By using the [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) function, you can change the text of the buttons. It would be something like

```
$action['#value'] = 'continue';
```

Please provide us with more code so I can work out a decent example.

Comment: I didn't use hook_form_alter() before. I will try it

Comment: I tried with the code I added at the bottom of my question. But not working. What am I missing?

Comment: Your form ID. What's your form ID? Also, the `$action['#value']` was just an example. You have to figure out your own structure via `var_dump`

Comment: the form id is 'views_form_commerce_cart_form_default'.

Answer (score 2):

In Drupal Commerce 8 on, the `hook_form_alter()` might not be able to catch the "Checkout" button, because the button is implemented in `commerce_checkout_form_alter()` in  `/commerce/modules/checkout/commerce_checkout.module`. So, depends on the name of your custom module, your custom `hook_form_alter()` might get called before `commerce_checkout`.

To make sure your custom module can see the "Checkout" button, go to your configuration: `config/sync/core.extension.yml`, lower your custom module weight, e.g. `custom_module: 1`. The number `1` is the weight of the module; bigger number means that module will get loaded/called later.

Answer (score 1):

You could be interested in the [Commerce Checkout Buttons](http://drupal.org/project/commerce_checkout_buttons) module.

> The Commerce Checkout Buttons module enables the use of shorter button values ​​on Drupal Commerce checkout pages.
>
> What exactly does the module?
>
> - All default ​​button values to be shortened to the shortest meaningful text.
>     Texts that are used:
>
>   - *Cancel* at the first checkout step.
>   - Back for further checkout steps.
>   - Continue at all checkout steps.
> - The button prefix or will be removed.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my answer to [Customize commerce cart form page](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/77405/customize-commerce-cart-form-page/), here's the section specific to the checkout button:

```
function yourthemename_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id)  {
  case 'views_form_commerce_cart_form_default': 

    $form['actions']['checkout']['#value'] = 'New checkout button label';

  break;
  }
}
```

See that above linked answer for the rest of the form!

Answer (score 0):

I am very new to drupal and I had the almost the same problem. I have to change the value of the checkout button and to make it translatable up to which language is selected. 
I tried different approaches but without any success.

I create a custom module with this function.

```
function md_custom_checkout_mod_form_commerce_checkout_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'commerce-checkout-form-checkout') {
    $form['submit']['#attributes']['title'] = t('Complete order');
  }
}

function md_custom_checkout_mod_form_commerce_checkout_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  if ($form_id == 'commerce-checkout-form-checkout') {
    $form['submit']['#attributes']['title'] = t('Complete order');
  }
}
```

Please can you give me some tips how to make this working.

Comment: Looks like you're also very new to using this site (bien venue!)... Please use the "Ask a question" button, instead of "posting an answer" to an existing question ... FYI: it's free ...

Answer (score 0):

In Drupal 8 / Commerce 2, you can add a string override to your settings.php file, as such:

```
/**
 * String overrides:
 *
 * To override specific strings on your site with or without enabling the Locale
 * module, add an entry to this list. This functionality allows you to change
 * a small number of your site's default English language interface strings.
 *
 * Remove the leading hash signs to enable.
 *
 * The "en" part of the variable name, is dynamic and can be any langcode of
 * any added language. (eg locale_custom_strings_de for german).
 */
# $settings['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = [
#   'forum'      => 'Discussion board',
#   '@count min' => '@count minutes',
# ];

 $settings['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = [
   'Checkout'      => 'CHECKOUT or GET QUOTE',
 ];
```

Specifically, this part:

```
 $settings['locale_custom_strings_en'][''] = [
   'Checkout'      => 'CHECKOUT or GET QUOTE',
 ];
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//exact code goes here

/*
I have also removed the update cart button here as I dont need you, you must have that code if you want it.
*/


function modulename_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if (strpos($form_id, 'views_form_commerce_cart_form_') === 0) {

    // Only alter buttons if the cart form View shows line items.

    $view = reset($form_state['build_info']['args']);

    if (!empty($view->result)) {


      // Unset update cart button as we dont need it.
      unset($form['actions']['submit']);

      //Change the name of checkout to - Delivery
       $form['actions']['checkout']['#value'] = t('Delivery');     
       $form['actions']['checkout']['#submit'] = array('memento_checkout_form_submit');

      // Change any Delete buttons to say Remove.
      if (!empty($form['edit_delete'])) {
        foreach (element_children($form['edit_delete']) as $key) {
          // Load and wrap the line item to have the title in the submit phase.
          if (!empty($form['edit_delete'][$key]['#line_item_id'])) {
            $line_item_id = $form['edit_delete'][$key]['#line_item_id'];
            $form_state['line_items'][$line_item_id] = commerce_line_item_load($line_item_id);

            $form['edit_delete'][$key]['#value'] = t('Remove');
            $form['edit_delete'][$key]['#submit'] = array_merge($form['#submit'], array('commerce_cart_line_item_delete_form_submit'));
          }
        }
      }

    }
    else {
      // Otherwise go ahead and remove any buttons from the View.
      unset($form['actions']);
    }
  }  
}
```