# Customize commerce cart form page

Tags: 7, views, commerce

## Task

I have been issued to alter the cart form view `Shopping cart form (Commerce Order)` on the `site.com/cart` page of the Drupal 7's commerce module. This includes adding extra choices such as sizes together with simply updating the quantity of each product.

## My attempts so far

I've tried overriding `commerce_cart_block` just realise it was `commerce_cart_form` that was in charge of the content. Now I've tried a module that's called [Commerce Cart View Override](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_cart_view_override) and it helps me have a template file called `views-view--commerce-cart-form.tpl.php` inside my template to display the content.

However I'm not really sure what I'm supposed to do now. In my mind I would override the table that show the items and the form surrounding it. I echo'ed `get_defined_vars()` in the template just to realise that there are quite many variables passed.

## Question

What I desire is an elegant solution that allows me to append more forms to modify existing cart session, all in the /cart page, and also be able to have full control of the current cart table.

What is the ideal way for me to customize the /cart page? Am I on the right path, or there some simplier alternatives that I have missed? Personally I want a coded solution and not a database saved one.

Comment: No offence but this just reads like a frustrated rant, it's difficult to understand what specific question you're asking. A better approach would be to include what you've already tried (including code, importantly), and what about that didn't work. You might not know yet but you're actually asking a bunch if different questions, the answers to which require a reasonably good knowledge of Drupal Commerce's workflow, and (more so) a good knowledge of Views theming. It's difficult to see how a single answer can address all the issues so I'd advise breaking it down into much smaller chunks

Comment: Sorry, I will try to break it up a bit. Sadly my patience and focus runs thin when I try to google an answer for what feels like forever without finding any documentation nor similiar problems with solution to guide me to the answer.

Comment: Believe me I sympathise (what programmer wouldn't?) I was only thinking about you actually getting answers - at the moment it's probably a bit much for a single person to take on. Try and break it down into individual tasks and attacking those one at a time. It'll be much easier for us to help you with that format, plus your questions will be useful to future visitors - everybody wins :)

Comment: Cleaned it up a bit hopefully. Thanks for your understanding. I have a bit more of a hard time getting along with Drupal then with CodeIgniter and also CakePHP. Feels like Drupal is alot about having faith to contrib modules, a faith which I don't have.

Answer (score 4):

### Editing the /cart page in Views

I think this is the expected approach. Note: this assumes you know your way around Views.

1. Install [Commerce Cart View Override](https://drupal.org/project/commerce_cart_view_override), as you've done.
2. Edit the view named Shopping Cart Form, clone it, change the machine name  to something starting with `commerce_cart_form` like `commerce_cart_form_custom`
3. Select this in the dropdown on the admin page `admin/commerce/config/cart-overrides` (Administer >> Store >> Configuration >> Cart Overrides), then save.
4. You can now edit the view that appears on the `/cart` page by editing this new view. A few non-intuitive tips:

   - To see a preview in the Views preview, you'll need to enter a shopping cart ID number into the "Preview with contextual filters" box above the preview. You can see some shopping cart ID numbers at `/admin/commerce/orders/carts`. You just enter the ID number, no other text needed.
   - To add any views fields from the products, for example **product images**, you'll need to add a new relationship from Line Items to Products. Under Advanced in the Views UI, under Relationships, click Add, then choose **Commerce Line item: Referenced products**. Product fields like images and taxonomy tags will then become available under Fields.
   - A common Commerce Cart configuration confusion: If no "Checkout" button appears for customers who aren't logged in, you need to go to `admin/people/permissions` and tick the "Anonymous user" box next to "Access checkout"
   - If you want to change the labels of buttons, for example the "Remove" buttons... that's a whole different story. Form elements are generated in a whole different part of the Drupal ecosystem and put into a View like this pre-rendered, all you can edit in Views is the labels that appear alongside or above the button. To edit the buttons themselves has to be PHP code:

### Editing form elements like buttons

In a custom module or your theme's template.php file (remember that if you use a seperate admin theme, your template.php won't have any effect in the views preview, only the customer-facing pages), add something like this ([credit](https://drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/change-delete-your-cart-x)):

```
function yourthemename_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id)  {
  case 'views_form_commerce_cart_form_custom_default': 
  //               ^ from here on should match the view machine name from earlier 
  //                                         ^ from here, the particular view display, which you can see at the end of the Views UI URL while editting that display 
      foreach ($form['edit_delete'] as $row_id => $row) {
        if(isset($form['edit_delete'][$row_id]['#value'])){
            $form['edit_delete'][$row_id]['#value'] = 'New delete button label';
            }
        }

    $form['actions']['checkout']['#value'] = 'New checkout button label';
    $form['actions']['submit']['#value'] = 'New update button label';

  break;
  }
}
```